# React Jest summary report not generated in Github runner

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, github-actions, cicd

I have a react application that contains the jest testing. To perform the test the command **yarn web:test:ui** is to be entered. There are atleast 20 tests to be performed by this command.

When ran in local machine the test are done properly and a summary report is generated by the jest as such.
[Local test summary report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhRZz.png)

when same code is ran in the github actions runner the tests are conducted but the summary report is not generated.
[Github actions UI test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aapd.png)

the yml file for the github/workflow is as such:

```
name: Run UI Tests with Enhanced Reporting
on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]  # Adjust branch(es) as needed
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # Adjust runner OS as needed
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3  # Checkout the repository code
      - name: Use Node.js with yarn
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 19.9.0  # Adjust Node.js version as needed

      - name: get yarn cache dir path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"
        
      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: yarn-cache
         # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Install project dependencies
        # if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'false'
        run: yarn --prefer-offline #yarn install
          

      - name: Run UI tests
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          cd ./packages
          yarn web:test:ui > test-results.txt  # Capture test output

      - name: Upload test results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test-results.txt
          path: test-results.txt

      - name: Store exit code
        id: store-exit-code
        continue-on-error: true
        run: echo "::set-output name=exit-code::$(yarn web:test:ui)"
        
      - name: Check test results
        if: steps.store-exit-code.outputs.exit-code != 0
        run: echo "Test suite failed with exit code ${{ steps.store-exit-code.outputs.exit-code }}"
```

tldr: the summary report is generated when ran in local machine , but not in runner of github actions.

i have tried with flags such as --coverage --verbose but no avail.

I have a react application that contains the jest testing. To perform the test the command **yarn web:test:ui** is to be entered. There are atleast 20 tests to be performed by this command.

When ran in local machine the test are done properly and a summary report is generated by the jest as such.
[Local test summary report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhRZz.png)

when same code is ran in the github actions runner the tests are conducted but the summary report is not generated.
[Github actions UI test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aapd.png)

the yml file for the github/workflow is as such:

```
name: Run UI Tests with Enhanced Reporting
on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]  # Adjust branch(es) as needed
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # Adjust runner OS as needed
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3  # Checkout the repository code
      - name: Use Node.js with yarn
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 19.9.0  # Adjust Node.js version as needed

      - name: get yarn cache dir path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"
        
      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: yarn-cache
         # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Install project dependencies
        # if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'false'
        run: yarn --prefer-offline #yarn install
          

      - name: Run UI tests
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          cd ./packages
          yarn web:test:ui > test-results.txt  # Capture test output

      - name: Upload test results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test-results.txt
          path: test-results.txt

      - name: Store exit code
        id: store-exit-code
        continue-on-error: true
        run: echo "::set-output name=exit-code::$(yarn web:test:ui)"
        
      - name: Check test results
        if: steps.store-exit-code.outputs.exit-code != 0
        run: echo "Test suite failed with exit code ${{ steps.store-exit-code.outputs.exit-code }}"
```

tldr: the summary report is generated when ran in local machine , but not in runner of github actions.

i have tried with flags such as --coverage --verbose but no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a github action for this
Link - https://github.com/MishaKav/jest-coverage-comment

```
- name: Jest Coverage Comment
  uses: MishaKav/jest-coverage-comment@main
  with:
    coverage-summary-path: ./coverage/coverage-summary.json
    title: My Jest Coverage Comment
    summary-title: My Summary Title
    badge-title: Coverage
    hide-comment: false
    create-new-comment: false
    hide-summary: false
    junitxml-title: My JUnit Title
    junitxml-path: ./coverage/junit.xml
    coverage-title: My Coverage Title
    coverage-path: ./coverage.txt
```